# can only concatenate list (not "str") to list in flask

Tags: python, list, email, flask, flask-mail

I am developing my own portfolio and about website and in contact form i want mail sender using flask but i am getting this error( can only concatenate list (not "str") to list).

I want that if anyone wanna send me message then i will get email.But i am facing the error.Need help.

```
@app.route("/contact",methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
      if(request.method=='POST'):
            
            
          
           name = request.form.get('name')
           email = request.form.get('email')
          
           message = request.form.get('message')
           
           msg = Message('Hello', sender = email, recipients = "husnainabbasi947514@gmail.com")
           msg.body = message
           mail.send(msg)
      return render_template('contact.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `recipients` argument expects a list which is why you get the error. Use this instead:

```
msg = Message('Hello', sender = email, recipients = ["husnainabbasi947514@gmail.com"])
```